# Cronjobs are not running for perl script?

Tags: perl, cron

---

Here is my crontab line:

```
* * * * * /home/data/use.pl
```

When i run perl use.pl it runs properly.I need to run the above file automatically without giving it manually every time like perl use.pl in terminal.So i tried to fix it by using cronjobs.But the above line not works for me.How can i revamp it.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: No error @ikegami

Comment: Of course there is, or you wouldn't be here. What is it doing wrong?

Comment: it is not running the perl file that is new.pl @ikegami

Comment: Why not? Is it a problem accessing the file, or is there a problem executing the script?

Comment: there is no error message when i execute the file separately in terminal i.e perl use.pl it runs properly.After including into cronjob also it is not showing any error messages. @ikegami

Comment: @gopi, did you not see the answer below? You are saying if you run `perl use.pl` it works, in cron you are not calling perl. Have a look at the below answer.

Comment: I thought you said it wasn't running `new.pl`. That would result in error message. How are you checking for errors? Is the mail system properly setup on that machine?

Comment: yes via mail system . @ikegami

Comment: Start by make sure the you can get errors by adding `* * * * * arghh`. If you don't get an error for that, then you need to fix that first, then provide the error you get when you try to run `use.pl`. If you do get an error for that, then you are wrong about `use.pl` not running.

Comment: @gopi so are you trying anything any of us suggested?

Comment: From my experience the most simple way to test for cron errors is piping the output(s) to a logfile. It's simpler than checking whether the mailsystem (where cron errors usually go) is set up properly. Try `* * * * * /home/data/use.pl 1>/tmp/1.log 2>/tmp/2.log` and then check the content of the two files, especially 2.log.

Answer (score 1):

The script does not have the relevant permissions for the user you are running it as. You can either do

```
chmod +x use.pl
```

or specify path to perl in crontab.

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/perl /home/data/use.pl
```

Comment: This only make the script executable. But maybe there are errors inside the script.

Comment: @Patrick85 he said that the script runs fine from shell, only not working in cron, he says when I run `perl use.pl` it works.

Comment: @Patrick85, You could both be right. You could both be wrong. It's possible that is a permission issue executing the script, and it's possible that it's a problem from the script itself (permission issue, assuming cwd = $RealBin, etc)

Comment: @ikegami That is why I am waiting on gopi to answer if he tried it.

Comment: Quite the opposite. Not only did you assume it was a missing exec flag and answered as if that was the problem, you rejected the possibility of an alternative problem. My comments points out that your dismissal of Patrick85's comment was incorrect by giving two examples of problems that could occur "inside the script".

Comment: @ikegami. I made the conclusion purely because the OP said _When i run `perl use.pl` it runs properly_ . That tells me that if he runs `./use.pl` it will not execute. So calling perl before the script or setting execute rights will most probably solve it.

Comment: I know your answer might be correct. I already said that. As for *probably* correct? I'm not so sure.

Comment: Yes, I am not arguing with you. Just explaining how I made my conclusion and answered. :)

Comment: What makes you think I didn't know???? I don't understand the point of any of your comments to me.

Comment: i honestly do not understand what your issue is here